# MongoClient issue - and not giving clear instructions

Tags: php, mongodb, connection

The issue I see to have ran into is the following

```
syscore::db(): The Mongo class is deprecated, please use the MongoClient class in /Users/russellharrower/www/bootstrap.localhost/system/core.php on line 11
```

The issue is that I was able to get it to work the old way and still it is saying it is wrong. As anone else had this issue.

here is how I am calling the connection.

```
class syscore{
static public $_db;
public static function db() 
{
 if (!static::$_db) {
    static::$_db = new MongoClient("mongodb://russell.harrower:25s4e8r14gGSWS362gyuAQDR!!@localhost:27017/russellharrower");
 }
 $siteDB = SITEDB;
 //return static::$_db->$siteDB;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The MongoClient class makes the connection. You select the database you want from the the returned connection. You appear to have commented that out BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're seeing would not be emitted from the code you've pasted, as you're clearly using MongoClient in lieu of the deprecated Mongo class. The following stand-alone script, consisting of a few additions to the non-functional snippet you provided, executes successfully and dumps a MongoDB object without an exception:

```
<?php

define('SITEDB', 'foo');

class syscore {
  static public $_db;
  public static function db() {
    if (!static::$_db) {
      static::$_db = new MongoClient();
    }
    $siteDB = SITEDB;
    return static::$_db->$siteDB;
  }
}

var_dump(syscore::db());
```

It should produce the following output:

```
object(MongoDB)#2 (2) {
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wtimeout"]=>
  int(10000)
}
```